# How to find the smallest maximum of a column with pandas after filtering?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, max, min

I have a dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'team': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
     'variable': [8, 9, 10, 11, 2, 3, 4, 5],
     'another_variable': [1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2]}
)
```

I would like to find the largest value of `variable` (which is counting upwards) where `another_variable` is still equal to 1.

I can group the data frame and filter the relevant rows:

```
df.groupby(['team']).apply(lambda g: g[g['another_variable'] == 1])

# Output:
#       team    variable    another_variable
#team               
#A  0   A       8           1
#   1   A       9           1
#   2   A       10          1
#B  4   B       2           1
#   5   B       3           1
```

But if I add `.variable.min()`, I only get a single value, instead of one value for each group (which I then could calculate the maximum of). What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filter first, then `groupby`:

```
df[df['another_variable'].eq(1)].groupby('team')['variable'].max()
```

Output:

```
team
A    10
B     3
Name: variable, dtype: int64
```

If there is a possibility that a group has no 1 and you'd like to have `NaN`, then use:

```
df['variable'].where(df['another_variable'].eq(1)).groupby(df['team']).max()
```

Example if there was no `1` in `A`:

```
team
A   NaN
B     3
Name: variable, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks! I just figured that out myself too, but I didn't know about that NaN issue, so thank you for elaborating! (I also still don't know why it does not work the other way around, but I suspect it's complicated, so I'd rather continue being oblivious :D)

Comment: @Maxim you could use `apply` (`df.groupby('team').apply(lambda g: g.loc[g['another_variable'] == 1, 'variable'].max())`) but this is not very fast ;)

Answer (score 0):

Following appears to be a variant of what Mozway has already proposed :

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'team': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
     'variable': [8, 9, 10, 11, 2, 3, 4, 5],
     'another_variable': [1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2]}
)

s = (df.groupby(['team', 'another_variable'])['variable']
       .max()
       .reset_index(['team', 'another_variable'])
       )

print( s[s['another_variable'].eq(1)] )
```

```
  team  another_variable  variable
0    A                 1        10
2    B                 1         3
```